# inserting multiple arrays in an order

Tags: java, mysql, jdbctemplate

I am having three Java String arrays,

```
String[] array1 = [a,b,c];
String[] array2 = [d,e];
String[] array3 = [f,g,h];
```

Now I have to insert these three arrays into mysql database in a below fashion

```
source         action        destination
    a                d             f
    b                d             f
    c                d             f 
    a                e             f
    b                e             f
    c                e             f
    a                d             g
    b                d             g
    c                d             g 
    a                e             g
    b                e             g
    c                e             g
    a                d             h
    b                d             h
    c                d             h 
    a                e             h
    b                e             h
    c                e             h
```

How can I achieve this using jdbcTemplate ?

Comment: Very carefully...? At least try; it'll make you feel good!

Comment: Each and every element of array1[] should be mapped to the elements of array2[] and array3[]. I couldn't think of any good logic to achieve this.

Comment: Emulate the pattern you provided in your post into code; that is the logic.

Answer (score 0):

have 3 for-loops, one for each array, have a SQL insert with each of the 3 indexes.

Do you know how to create for-loops?

Do you know how to insert data into mysql?

Do you know how to use jdbctemplate?

Comment: do you mean nested for-loops or separate for-loops

Comment: i think he mean nested for-loops, but if the number of arrays  is dynamic then this strategy with not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the logic finally. Its pretty simple and sorry for disturbing you with that silly question. Thanks a million times to those who tried to help me. The code goes as below.

```
if(array2.length > array3.length)
{
for(int k=0; k<array2.length; k++)
{
for(int l=0; l<array3.length; l++)
{
for(int j=0; j < array1.length ; j++)
{                                       dataServices.newLinkInsert(array1[j],array2[l],array3[k]);

}
}
}
}
else
{
for(int k=0; k<array3.length; k++)
{
for(int l=0; l<array2.length; l++)
{
for(int j=0; j < array1.length ; j++)
{
   dataServices.newLinkInsert(array1[j],array2[l],array3[k]);                                           
}
}
}
}
```